# Nested GridView in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested

I need create `Nested GridView` in `ASP.NET` using `C#`.

This is the tutorial: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/nested-gridview-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1011.aspx

My problem is when set `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the first `GridView`

If setting on `GridView` is

```
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```

the return is
[image]

Instead if setting on `GridView` is

```
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
```

the return is
[image]

I need set `AutoGenerateColumns` property `True` always

I can't have a `Nested GridView` if I use `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` ?

Comment: Imagine if you'd [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns): "Write custom code to automatically generate fields by creating and assigning your own ColumnsGenerator class and assigning an instance of it to the control."

Comment: @IanKemp What do you mean?

Comment: @IanKemp Resolved with new tutorial https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Collapsible-Nested-GridView-with-Paging-using-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Yes you can have nested Grid with auto generated columns. But I would use TemplateField.